# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at eval (external_"fs":1)

Tags: typescript, pdf, npm, webpack

Why am I getting error, described in title, even though I am not explicitly using 'fs'

I tried 2 libraries 'dynamic-html-pdf' and 'phantom-html2pdf' to generate pdf from HTML on client side but I get same error. I know internally both these libraries uses "fs". 

What am I doing wrong? Most of the answers I saw talks about putting either of following code in webpack.config.js

```
target: 'node'
```

or

```
node: { fs: "empty" }
```

That seems to compile code but at runtime I get same error described in title.

> My TypeScript code:

```
import pdf from "phantom-html2pdf";

function DownloadPdf() {
    alert("Message from PDF.ts");

    var pdfOptions = {
        'html': '<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><body><h1>Hello</h1><p>World</p></body></html>',
        'papersize': { format: 'A4', orientation: 'portrait', border: '1cm' }
    };

    pdf.convert(pdfOptions, function (err, result) {

        /* Using a buffer and callback */
        result.toBuffer(function (returnedBuffer) { });

        /* Using a readable stream */
        var stream = result.toStream();

        /* Using the temp file path */
        var tmpPath = result.getTmpPath();

        /* Using the file writer and callback */
        result.toFile("/path/to/file.pdf", function () { });
    });
}

document.getElementById('Pdf').addEventListener('click', DownloadPdf);
```

Comment: Alvin - I'm having the same issue.  I've tried the two solutions you've mentioned above, but like you get an error at RunTime.  Any luck ?